# Imprimir texto em ASCII

Tags: vb.net, impressora, ascii

Boa tarde, estou tentando imprimir um texto (Código ZPL), porém no meu código existem delimitadores ASCII, e por esse motivo não gera impressão correta, ou seja faltando determinados caracteres. Alguém sabe algum método para gerar impressão contendo todos os caracteres ASCII.

Obs.: Estou tentando imprimir em código de barras 2D PDF(147).

Segue como tentei imprimir abaixo:
Tentativa 1

```
Shell("print /D:\\ & caminhoImpressora &  "C:\ETIQUETA.TXT", ppWinStyle.Hide)
```

Tentativa 2

```
Impressao.SendStringToPrinter("caminhoImpressora", "texto")

Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO

Public Class Impressao
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Public Class DOCINFOA
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> _
        Public pDocName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> _
        Public pOutputFile As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> _
        Public pDataType As String
    End Class

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="OpenPrinterA", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function OpenPrinter(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal szPrinter As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="ClosePrinter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function ClosePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function StartDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal level As Int32, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal di As DOCINFOA) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="EndDocPrinter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function EndDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="StartPagePrinter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function StartPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="EndPagePrinter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function EndPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="WritePrinter", SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Friend Shared Function WritePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCount As Int32, ByRef dwWritten As Int32) As Boolean
    End Function

#Region "Metodos"

    Friend Shared Function SendBytesToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCount As Int32) As Boolean
        Dim dwError As Integer = 0, dwWritten As Integer = 0
        Dim hPrinter = New IntPtr(0)
        Dim di = New DOCINFOA()
        Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False 'Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "Impressao Automatica"
        di.pDataType = "RAW"

        'Abre o método OpenPrinter
        If OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero) Then
            'Incia o documento.
            If (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di)) Then
                'Inicia a página.
                If (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)) Then
                    'Escreve os bytes na impressora.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, dwWritten)
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
                End If
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
            End If
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
        End If
        'Caso exista algum erro, retorna o erro.
        If bSuccess = False Then
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
        End If
        Return bSuccess
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function SendFileToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal szFileName As String) As Boolean
        'Abre o arquivo
        Dim fs = New FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open)
        'Cria um objeto BinaryReader com o arquivo.
        Dim br = New BinaryReader(fs)
        'Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Dim bytes(fs.Length) As Byte
        Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
        'Your unmanaged pointer.
        Dim pUnmanagedBytes = New IntPtr(0)
        Dim nLength As Integer

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)
        'Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength)
        'Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength)
        'Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength)
        'Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength)
        'Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes)
        Return bSuccess
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function SendStringToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal szString As String) As Boolean
        Dim pBytes As IntPtr
        Dim dwCount As Integer
        'How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length
        ' Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        ' the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString)
        'Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes)
        Return True
    End Function

#End Region
```

Comment: Quais os caracteres que estão dando problema? É provável que você tenha de substituir todos os caracteres cujo código ASCII seja inferior a 32, pois de regra eles não são imprimíveis, ou têm significados especiais para a impressora (p. ex. Form Feed, Line Feed, Carriage Return).

Comment: Estou com problema no chr(30) "Record Separator" e chr(4) "End Of Transm.", são os únicos carácteres especiais que estão dando problema, o chr(29) "Group Separator" funciona corretamente.

Comment: Na página 1280 do [Guia de Programação ZPL](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) está indicado que esses caracteres não são recomendados. Suponho que você vai ter que fazer uma iteração no seu byte array para substituí-los por outro caractere.

Comment: Muito Obrigado VBobCat, eu não tinha me atentado ao detalhe do manual.